# Heroku messing up styles

Tags: css, heroku

I recently deployed my Ruby application to Heroku and noticed that the styles on the HerokuApp appeared to be not loading. The pictures wouldn't show up, and everything looked terrible. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

### Rails asset pipeline

The problem you're observing is what happens if the Rails asset pipeline is not functioning properly: the CSS references and the photo URLs are likely returning 404 errors. A way to resolve this is to precompile your assets (CSS, js, image references) locally, prior to pushing to Heroku.

### Asset precompile

To precompile your assets on development platform for production prior to deploying to Heroku.

1. Include this line in production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

2. Run the assets precompile on your development platform

```
$bundle exec rake assets:precompile RALIS_ENV=production
```

3. Push to Heroku for deploy

### Notes

- Watch the messages logged during Heroku slug generation. It should
  display something like 'assets precompiled, not compiling before
  generating slug...' (That's not the exact language, but look for the
  message that tells you Heroku has detected assets are precompiled.)
- Use the browser debug inspector to probe and see the URLs for the images. There, you can see how the asset
  s pipeline differs from the raw precompiled structure and filenames.

### "The Asset Pipeline" Documentation

Rails documentation on the asset pipeline is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).